# How to iterate through all the sublayers in Framer

Tags: coffeescript, framerjs

sorry for stupid question, i need to animate all sublayers in some particular layer. How to iterate through all the sublayers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate sublayers of a layer via for-in loop

```
for child in layer.subLayers
    child.animate
        properties: 
            x: Utils.randomNumber(100)
            y: Utils.randomNumber(100)
```

if you need an index of each sublayer, you can change loop like this

```
for child, i in layer.subLayers
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this recursively?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question looking for a similar solution.  I wanted to change all subLayers in a given layer, even deep nested layers.  In the Docs I found descendants.  Adding here in case someone is looking for a solution to iterate all nested subLayers.

```
for descendant in layers
    descendant.ignoreEvents
```